# Merging dataframes with multiple columns in common

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple csv files corresponding to the access grades to college in my country, divided by years.

Every csv file is composed of 7 columns:

```
"Institution Code", "Curse Code", "Institution", "Course", NrVacanciesYear", "NrPlacedYear", "LastGradeYear".
```

I'm trying to concatenate 21 files (from the year 1997 to 2018) into a single one, where it concatenates the columns by year.

I'm trying to use

```
dffinal_conc = pd.concat([df18, df17], ignore_index=True)
```

but I'm having problems grouping by "Institution Code" and "Course Code" (NOTE: same courses from different institution have the same ID!)

When I try to use this

```
dffinal_conc = pd.concat([df18, df17], axis = 1)
```

it kinda groups by Course and Institution code but I don't know if I'm doing it properly, when I try to use

```
dffinal_conc['Código Curso'].value_counts()
```

to verify that there is only 1 value by ID, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'"

(NOTE: I used `dffinal_conc2.loc[:,~dffinal_conc2.columns.duplicated()]` to remove duplicates)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: make 2 small dataframes which will depict your problem statement and show us a sample output based on the 2 sample input dataframes. You can take help from here: [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

put all your csv files into one folder and try this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob


temp = pd.DataFrame()

path_to_csv = '/folder/of/csvs/' 

csv_pattern = os.path.join(path_to_csv,'*.csv')
file_list = glob.glob(csv_pattern)

for file in file_list:
    df = pd.read_csv(file , header= True)
    temp = temp.append(df, sort = True)

temp
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The output was a df with size 22446 x 70, the number of columns is right, the problem is that the max row should be 1068, based on the last year csv.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The output was a df with size 22446 x 70, the number of columns is right, the problem is that the max row should be 1068, based on the last year csv.
I tried to saw the df wiht missingo and the result was this https://imgur.com/a/LwlA0MH